# Quadratic equation form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, quadratic-forms, quadratics

I have the relation 
  $u=\sqrt{(a_1+b_1t)^2+(a_2+b_2t)^2+(a_3+b_3t)^2} \tag 1$

I need to write $t$ as a function of $u$ ($t=f(u)$). How will I get that ?

NB: $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3$ are constants

Comment: Square everything. Expand. Condense. Solve the quadratic in $t$.

Comment: Actually I need to do that in substitution in integration. What if it may end in no root? Then my integration result work only for certain values of constants only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you square both sides, you get
$$
u^{2}=\left(a_{1}+b_{1}t\right)^{2}+\left(a_{2}+b_{2}t\right)^{2}+\left(a_{3}+b_{3}t\right){}^{2}.
$$
Then, expanding,
\begin{align*}
u^{2} & =\sum_{n=1}^{3}a_{n}^{2}+2a_{n}b_{n}t+b_{n}^{2}t^{2}\\
 & =\left(\sum a_{n}^2\right)+\left(2\sum a_{n}b_{n}\right)t+\left(\sum b_{n}^{2}\right)t^{2}
\end{align*}
and now we have a quadratic equation for $u^{2}$ in terms of $t$.
$$
u=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-2\sum\left(a_{n}b_{n}\right)\pm\sqrt{4\left(\sum a_{n}b_{n}\right)^{2}-4\left(\sum a_{n}^2\right)\left(\sum b_{n}^{2}\right)}}{2\sum a_{n}^2}.}
$$

Simplify this further to get
$$
u=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sum\left(a_{n}b_{n}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(\sum a_{n}b_{n}\right)^{2}-\left(\sum a_{n}^{2}\right)\left(\sum b_{n}^{2}\right)}}{\sum a_{n}^{2}}}
$$
Thanks to Claude Leibovici for pointing out my mistake. Now, due to
the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\left(\sum a_{n}b_{n}\right)^{2}\leq\sum a_{n}^{2}\sum b_{n}^{2}
$$
and hence
$$
u=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sum\left(a_{n}b_{n}\right)\pm i\sqrt{\left(\sum a_{n}^{2}\right)\left(\sum b_{n}^{2}\right)-\left(\sum a_{n}b_{n}\right)^{2}}}{\sum a_{n}^{2}}}
$$
with the quantity in the innermost square root being nonnegative.

Comment: Actually I need to do that in substitution in integration. What if it may end in no root? Then my integration result work only for certain values of constants only

Comment: Can we guarantee that inside those square roots, there never comes a negative value

Comment: Is there any other format,so that we can write t as a function of u and works for all constants

Comment: @par. You have two typo's : there are three places where $\sum a_{n}$ should be $\sum a^2_{n}$. I let you editing your answer.